# How to detect multiple colors other than a particular color in image processing with Python using openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I was trying to detect multiple colors simultaneously in an video, So I made a code including trackbar to adjust `hsv` values. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
def nothing(x):
    pass
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.createTrackbar('lh','image',0,180,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('ls','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('lv','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('hh','image',0,180,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('hs','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('hv','image',0,255,nothing)
while(True):
    ret, img = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lh = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lh','image')
    ls = cv2.getTrackbarPos('ls','image')
    lv = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lv','image')
    hh = cv2.getTrackbarPos('hh','image')
    hs = cv2.getTrackbarPos('hs','image')
    hv = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lv','image')
    lr = np.array([lh,ls,lv])
    hr = np.array([hh,hs,hv])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lr,hr)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = mask)
    cv2.imshow('image',res)
    if(cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF==ord(' ')):
        break
cap.release()    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The problem I encountered here is that when I run this program all I can see is a black screen. Even though I moved the trackbars, it was still showing black screen. But when I tried running this program removing the trackbars for higher range, by specifying the range in the code itself for a particular color it was working.

For example I changed the code :

```
hr = np.array([120,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lr,hr)
```

How can I make this code work for all colors?